# imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"] does not show image

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiimageview, uiimage

Assigning the image directly through storyboard works fine (which means images are there in resources).
but trying same in code doesn't work.
What might go wrong.
any ideas ?

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
 if (userStatus) 
_userNameImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"wrong.png"];
 });
```

images removed and added again,
images named checked,
imageview is properly mapped with storyboard.

Thanks

Comment: have you checked if `userStatus` is true?

Comment: yes sir, i have checked userStatus is true

Comment: Is there any reason you have wrote this code with `dispatch_async `? If no, try taking this out of it (as you will be in main thread itself).

Comment: Are you sure _userNameImageView IBOutlet connected ?

Comment: yes because NSURLSessionDataTask works on background thread.

Comment: @yogendra yes it is well connected

Comment: You can try to remove this dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

Comment: check image name 'wrong.png' with capital small letter, also check  you have checked referenced when image added to project.

Comment: thanks every one , i found it , it was all messed up in more than 1000 lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things to check.

1. Check if the code is executing.
2. Remove and add images again and check mark copy option.
3. check if the image view is properly mapped with storyboard.
4. check if the image view is not hidden.
5. Add below code to make the image in original proportion.

   self.myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;